# SDL_QUIT event doesn't happen in SDL_PollEvent loop

Tags: linux, loops, sdl, xorg

My main loop function in my SDL2 application looks like this:

```
SDL_Event e;
while (win.GetOpen()) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) win.Close();
    }
}
```

And it does not work. Putting an `std::cout` in the loop during the SDL_QUIT `if` does not print anything. Am I doing something wrong here? My window class constructor and destructor are:

```
Window::Window(const char* title, int x, int y, int w, int h, SDL_Surface* icon = IMG_Load("icon.png")) {
    this->Position.x = x;
    this->Position.y = y;
    this->Position.w = w;
    this->Position.h = h;

    this->Win = SDL_CreateWindow(title, this->Position.x, this->Position.y, this->Position.w, this->Position.h, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    this->Renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(this->GetWin(), -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    this->WindowIcon = icon;
    SDL_SetWindowIcon(this->GetWin(), this->WindowIcon);

    this->Open = true;
}
Window::~Window() {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(this->Win);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(this->Renderer);
    SDL_FreeSurface(this->WindowIcon);
}
```

This seems fine to me, so I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with my code. `Window::GetOpen()` returns the bool `Open` and `Window::Close()` sets `Open` to false, supposedly ending the game loop.

Comment: `SDL_QUIT` fired at last window close; do you have multiple windows? Can you reproduce it without your window class? Consider making [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if problem persists.

Comment: I do not have multiple windows @keltar. When you say "`SDL_QUIT` fired at last window close;", do you mean you tried it out and it worked?

Comment: Don't know, I use it all the time. If you have problem with that - most likely it is in some other code that we don't see; once again, not getting anywhere without MCVE. My best guess is you actualy have more windows than you think you do.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but try something like this:

```
SDL_Event event;
while (running)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        std::cout << "Polling events" << std::endl;
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
            std::cout << "Quit program!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

and see if you get any output.

Edit:  Make a new project (yeah I know its a massive pain lol) and use this in a single file, lmk if it works as it should

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Program", 0, 30, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);// | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );


    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;

    while (running){
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

       

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put three `cout`s, one in the `running` loop, one in the `PollEvent` loop, and one in the `SDL_QUIT`. The running and event `cout`s were printed. After pressing close the `SDL_QUIT` one was not.

Comment: try make a tiny program that just does a clear mainloop with just events and rendering, like 100 lines of code or something. Acutally I think I probably have one lying around. Try that first and see if it still doesn't work